# Weird iOS UIWebView Crash called WTF Crash

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash

I am using UIWebViews in some of the screens, because I need a perfect Html text parsing.

According to crash reports a huge number of crashes, called WTF Crash, occur on these screens. Here is a trace of that crash

```
Crashed: WebThread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000bbadbeef

Thread : Crashed: WebThread
0  JavaScriptCore                 0x184fd2710 WTFCrash + 72
1  JavaScriptCore                 0x184fd2708 WTFCrash + 64
2  WebCore                        0x1852b7d78 <redacted> + 362
3  WebCore                        0x1852b7bec <redacted> + 44
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1817d8588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1817d632c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1817d6674 __CFRunLoopRun + 696
7  CoreFoundation                 0x181705680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
8  WebCore                        0x1852b5998 <redacted> + 456
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18148bb28 <redacted> + 156
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18148ba8c _pthread_start + 154
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181489028 thread_start + 4
```

There is no OS version, or device relation on this crash.

I am not doing anything fancy on using UIWebView as well. It is added to nib like every other component, and in the implementation file I use it like the following

```
self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
self.webView.opaque = NO;
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.webView.delegate = self;
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Any suggestions on how to solve WTF Crash?

Edit: Here is how htmlString looks like

```
Printing description of htmlString:
<html><body style="font-family:HelveticaNeue; font-size:10; background-color:#E5E4E4; text-align:left; color:#696969 ">test string</body></html>
```

Comment: WTF crash!  .   .  ....

Comment: Relevant [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159798/should-i-avoid-creating-jscontexts-in-global-queues)

Comment: What is your "htmlString" you are referring?

Comment: check whether didReceiveMemoryWarning is called at any point of time where you are creating webView.

Comment: @Vizllx Added htmlString description to the end of question. Also checked about memory warning. didReceiveMemoryWarning is not called

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Jan still looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are creating your UIWebView. But I was having a similiar issue with a WTFCrash and I was able to solve it by making sure that the UIWebView was being created on the main thread:

```
- (void)createWebView{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self createWebView];
        });
        return;
    }
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    //Rest of my code
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this ?

Comment: @Jitendra I'm sure that this fixed my particular problem with a WTFCrash, not sure about the OP

Comment: My WebView creation logic is on main thread only still I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you debugging your web view with Safari? If yes, the crash should be gone after you quit Safari.

I was facing a similar crash with WKWebView, and I was sure the same code worked happily 3 days ago. `hlung`'s comments saved me, you can find it [HERE](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10346).

For your reference, following is a piece of the crash log in my case.

> ```
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
> Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000dbbdfb10
> Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog:
> None found
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:
> 0   JavaScriptCore                  0x225d74c6 WTF::HashSet<JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer*, WTF::PtrHash<JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer*>, WTF::HashTraits<JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer*> >::remove(JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer* const&) + 54
> 1   JavaScriptCore                  0x22620b41 JSC::VM::~VM() + 211
> 2   JavaScriptCore                  0x22197e57 JSC::JSLockHolder::~JSLockHolder() + 73
> 3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2248defd JSContextGroupRelease + 61
> 4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2250e37d -[JSVirtualMachine dealloc] + 27
> 5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1dac5195 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 239
> 6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2248d261 -[JSContext dealloc] + 125
> 7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1dac5195 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 239
> 8   JavaScriptCore                  0x226470af WTF::RunLoop::TimerBase::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 25
> 9   CoreFoundation                  0x1e807357 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 15
> 10  CoreFoundation                  0x1e807029 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 897
> 11  CoreFoundation                  0x1e8069e1 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 221
> 12  CoreFoundation                  0x1e804cc5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1365
> 13  CoreFoundation                  0x1e754073 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
> 14  CoreFoundation                  0x1e753e81 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
> 15  GraphicsServices                0x1ff00bfd GSEventRunModal + 157
> 16  UIKit                           0x2390e82f -[UIApplication _run] + 575
> 17  UIKit                           0x23908f61 UIApplicationMain + 151
> 18  MyApp                           0x00488b29 0x2c000 + 4573993
> 19  libdyld.dylib                   0x1df1e50b start + 3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

WebKit, the engine behind Web Views, can raise a crash when it sees a memory problem.
These are identified by the special Hex Word `0x00000000bbadbeef` as you have found.

The web page you are visiting seems trivial, so it is a surprise that you are having problems.  I recommend you follow the WebKit debugging facilities described at:
https://webkit.org/debugging-webkit/#ios-simulator

Please update your question with any logs or insights this reveals.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Google Ads issue, already fixed for sure on version 7.35.0 of October, 17 and newer versions.

You should be able to fix the issue updating your pod.

From the *Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers Team* mailing:

> "The issue has been fixed by the team and it should go live in an upcoming SDK release (release notes)." (August, 20)
>
> "Issue has been fixed and live already." (October, 17)

**Source:** https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/XL35wo6mQts/R2LlGZDxBwAJ

**Release Notes:** https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes